# DB Replicating from different publisher to a sing subscriber

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I have 3 databases on a SQL server instance

```
- DataBase_A
- DataBase_B
- DataBase_C
```

Each database have 3 tables, that are identical in their schema, but different in their data content

```
- Table 1
- Table 2
- Table 3
```

I need to set up replication of the 3 tables from all 3 databases to a single agregate datatabase - `DataBase_Combined` on the same server instance, containing all those 3 tables agreagating each its respective data.

When I set up the replication (used snapshot replication type)
I have 3 publication

```
- Database 1_combined
- Database 2_combined
- Database 3_combined
```

I see that the data gets overwritten in the destination `DataBase_Combined`  by each subsequent snapshot.
So, the **`Table 1`**  would only have the data from the **`Database 3`**, because its snapshot ran last.

Looking into the snapshot folder configured, in the file for a particular table `- Table 1.sch`, I see that there are statements to drop a table and then create it.

This would explain to me why the data gets overwritten.

**Question 1:**  Is my understanding correct in this regard ?  Or am I off ?

**Question 2:**  How can I set up the replication correctly to aggregate the data as outlined above ?  Ideally, I need the task to run every hour.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. You don't; that's not how replication works.

Comment: @Tom A:  Thank you for the clarification.  So, is the only option here to create stored procedure to aggregate the data (union all, etc,,) and have a MERGE statement on a XX_Combined database ?

Comment: Shouldn't you use merge replication for this task?

Comment: @suggermannen:  that is a nature of my question.  I am looking for clarification.

Comment: Have you read the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-ver16 ? There are a couple of types and i'm not sure exactly what fits your case best

Comment: But, let me ask you this question, why do you need replication if you're on the same server? I've been following your questions and you've been doing this replication thing for a while now. Replication is usually for far away servers (in my opinion)

Comment: in my requirements i had a term "replicate every hour" .. so I assumed she meant replication.  But to answer YOUR question - IF I do NOT need a replication, then that would be an answer I am looking for.

Comment: If it's just three tables, i'd probably just create a manual script that does the union / merge thing :)

Comment: @siggemannen:  this is what I ended up doing.